# Android refresh Bluetooth device list after specific time

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I use [Android developer guide for Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)  to list all nearby Bluetooth devices ,i use following code.

```
// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
};
// Register the BroadcastReceiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
```

update the view.

```
ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
    newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
```

Now i want to update the list after every 10 second how i can do it.

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Timer` and `TimerTask` (from Java)

First you have to register the receiver

```
//THIS IS YOUR CODE
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            //IMPORTANT: Do not remove lines below
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
    }
};
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

After, do this:

```
final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
TimerTask mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    //After cancel discovery, start discovery instead of wait another 10 seconds to re-execute this piece of code
                    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                } else {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                }
            }

        });
        //Timer delays 0 seconds (it will start immediately)
        //Timer repeats every 10 seconds, as you said
        //10000ms equals to 10s
        mTimer.schedule(mTimerTask, 0, 10000);
    }

};
```